# A new tag for new version of a library/software?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

I see that we have about four or five separate tags for `ExtJs` in Stack Overflow. Actually a new tag for a new version. For example we have [extjs4](/questions/tagged/extjs4), [extjs](/questions/tagged/extjs) and [extjs4.1](/questions/tagged/extjs4.1) and maybe more ExtJs tags because Sencha releases a new version of ExtJs every 2 month.

I think we should have one ExtJs tag, and no more. How we can fix this problem?

Comment: Why? This is your post, you need to provide reasoning to convince everyone...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards By "Why?" you mean I should provide acceptable reasons why we should have one tag for that?

Comment: Version-specific tags are a needed evil.  Unfortunately some people mistake "my question is about a thing specific to version x.y" with "I'm using version x.y but it doesn't matter in the least," which is very, very silly here.  Because we don't have (and won't get) nested or hierarchical tags, separate versioned tags are things we're going to have to live with ... in appropriate moderation.

Comment: Yes @Afshin, what's the problem with having multiple version tags?

Answer (score 1):

The documentations of extjs different versions differ. So, I believe there should be different tags for each version of extjs. For example, Some of the problems of `Extjs 3` has been solved in `Extjs 4`.

If you are using a version whose tag is not available on SO then mention the version in your post with the common tag `extjs`.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a problem because;

- Every question posted *ever* would potentially be market with the "new version" tag.
- It would not be persistant since the "new version" tag would only be valid until the next version is out and this defeats the goal of stackoverflow being a library of generic answers.